# HP P410i as online spare

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, redundancy, sas, hp-smart-array

Is it possible to have dual P410i SAS controllers and use one for a online spare? I am fairly new to HP servers and I will be setting up a new G7 for production use.

I have been reading about HP's S.M.A.R.T. but have not seen the option to make a controller redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wouldn't worry about controller failure with internal disks. The controller failure rate is pretty low, and there are other ways to achieve redundancy. You may have some options if you were using an external enclosure like a D2600 or D2700, but for internal disks, there's no solution. Which server model is this?

Also see the [quickspecs for the controller](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13201_na/13201_na.html).

Comment: It is a HP DL385

Comment: Yeah, there's no standby controller option.

Comment: Not to say it couldn't happen, but I've never seen a P-Series SA Controller make it through burn-in, then fail later on.

Comment: I've had one P400 fail in 2007, and an 532 in 2004. The controllers are pretty robust, but be sure to keep track of firmware revisions and change logs, since new functionality is often added during the product's lifecycle.